# How to change the scroll bar style in QTextBrowser?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I cant change th e style of this scroll bar which is in QTextBrowser:

[image: img of app]

also code from other answers doesnt work

*I use ui file and big part of css is in it

### Code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFile, QTextStream
import datetime
import keyboard
import pyautogui

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
ui = uic.loadUi("data/design.ui")

ui.setWindowIcon(QIcon("data/img.jpg"))
ui.setWindowTitle("color_picker")


def change_bind():
    global hotkey_
    keyboard.remove_hotkey(hotkey_)
    hotkey = keyboard.read_event(suppress=True)
    keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey.name, change_color)

    ui.current_key.setText(hotkey.name)
    hotkey_ = hotkey.name


def change_color():
    x, y = pyautogui.position()
    color = pyautogui.pixel(x, y)
    hex_color = '#{:02x}{:02x}{:02x}'.format(*color)
    font_size = "12px"
    text = f"<span style='color: #1B2223; font-size: {font_size};'>[{datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M')}]</span>\
             <span style='color: #0EF6CC; font-size: {font_size};'> {hex_color}\n</span>"
    ui.history.insertHtml(text)


css_file = QFile("data/style.css")
if css_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly | QFile.Text):
    stream = QTextStream(css_file)
    css_content = stream.readAll()
    css_file.close()
    ui.setStyleSheet(css_content)

hotkey_ = 'alt'
keyboard.add_hotkey(hotkey_, change_color)
ui.change_key.clicked.connect(change_bind)
ui.show()
app.exec()
```

### Css:

```
QMainWindow {
    background-color: #1B2223;
}
```

Comment: From the image, you probably have set stylesheets in the UI using generic properties, which should be avoided for containers or complex widgets (windows, frames, scroll areas, etc). Always prefer [proper selector types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) and read the [reference documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html) to know how to properly style elements of complex widgets.

Answer (score 0):

lmao, PyQt never had css, it has QSS, which is something Qt invented that looks very similar to css.

in your case, you just want to change `QScrollBar:vertical` (which is not something that exists in css).
unless you plan on making your window dynamic, just using

```
QScrollBar:vertical { (add the changes you want here) }
```

inside `data/style.css` should fix it.

btw, if you want to learn more, [this video](https://youtu.be/TAL_CUH2cyI?si=jwpIvPMqCyFkUfuW) should hopefully explain the basics of qss, and you can just use chatgpt for the rest

Comment: thx, can you show an example, cose it doesn't work for me for some reason